# Eclipse Plugin Development - Reload Plugin Changes without restarting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I just started to develop an Eclipse Plugin. I run the plugin as EclipseApplication. When I make a change in my code I currently have to exit the EclipseApplication and restart it.

Isn't there some hot switching without restarting eclipse all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse can reload the classes (with some limitations - eg:  method signature changes, etc.) if you start your runtime workspace in `Debug` mode